# Quero salvar os dados em um arquivo de texto com python, mas ocorre o erro: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'agenda.txta+'

Tags: python

```
#Quero criar um arquivo assim que o programa rodar pela primeira vez

def novo_contato():
    print('\n=== NOVO CONTATO ===')
    nome = input(' Nome: ')
    numero = int(input(' Número: '))
    email = input(' E-mail: ')
    try: #TRATAMENTO DE ERRO & SALVANDO CONTATO EM UM ARQUIVO
        arquivo = open("agenda.txt" "a")
        dados = f'{nome};{numero};{email}\n'
        arquivo.write(dados)
        arquivo.close()
        print('\n --- CONTATO SALVO COM SUCESSO! --- \n')
    except:
        print("\n --- ERRO AO SALVAR CONTATO!! --- \n")
```

Comment: O erro que está sendo exibido para você diz que o arquivo **agenda.txt** não existe no diretório que está em foco.

Comment: virgula na abertura do arquivo, ta faltando

Comment: Como que eu não vi isso? Muito obrigado! funcionou certinho agora. Sempre são as vírgulas.